# dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/lib/swift/libswiftWebKit.dylib

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm getting this error when I run my app through ***iphone 6s ios version 13.1.2*** but it is workin with ***ios version 14 and up***. I tried deleting Pods, brew update, brew upgrade, brew cleanup and update my xcode to latest version but I still get this error. How to fix this error? thank you so much!

Comment: I am having the same issue, have you resolved it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same error and fixed it by going into my app in Xcode under the Project Navigator, then opening Frameworks, and deleting `libSwiftWebKit.tbd`. I had recently updated the deployment target to IOS 12 as well as updated the Podfile, which I think had something to do with it. I think there was a bug in an earlier version of Xcode or my Podfile settings, whereby I had to include `libSwiftWebKit.tbd` manually, but after recent updates, that was fixed such that it doesn't need to be included manually anymore.

Comment: Excellent solution for my React Native app.  Thanks!

Comment: Our app worked on ios 16, but not in 13.6. Work now with your solution, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue and was exhausted with that because I tried different other suggestions but all were in vain. In the end, **Deleting** the **Build folder** from Xcode brought me luck.

So my suggestion will be, first of all, to try to

> **Delete the Build folder** (Xcode > Products > Clean Build Folder) or (Shift+Command+K)

If it doesn't work then try other options.